# Impedir que objeto substitua os demais em ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist

Tenho dois laços de repetição que tem como função substituir textos por outros valores.

O problema começa quando eu mando adicionar um objeto em um `ArrayList`, no caso o objeto `clone`. A adição está no segundo laço por que o sistema gera resultado diferente para cada `ingrediente`.

Até a linha `clone.getF().setCalculo(tempA);` tudo ocorre normal, mas quando passa para a linha `novosItems.add(contaItem, clone);` tudo começa a dar errado.

O objeto `clone` que está sendo adicionado substitui todos os objetos contidos no `ArrayList`. Estranhamente apenas com um valor que ocorre esse erro. Para exemplificar o que ocorre veja esse exemplo:

```
//Um arrayList comum 
ArrayList<objeto> lista = new ArrayList<>();
//valores do arrayList lista
[0] = "Maria", "12"
[1] = "João", "10"
[2] = "Carlos", "33"
```

Agora imagine que toda vez que se adiciona algo novo no `ArrayList` todos os valores que seriam o nome por exemplo passam a ter o mesmo valor do último inserido, mas as idades não sofrem alteração.

```
lista.add("Roberto")
[0] = "Roberto", "12"
[1] = "Roberto", "10"
[2] = "Roberto", "33"
[3] = "Roberto", "22"
```

Abaixo está o código que tá com esse problema.

```
for (Item item : this.tabela.getItem()) {
    // Ingredientes
    final String[] formulainicial = item.getF().getCalculo().clone();
    Item clone = item;

    for (Ingrediente ingrediente : this.tabela.getIngredite()) {

        String tempA[];
        tempA = formulainicial.clone();

        //Subistitue o nome do ingrediente pelo seu valor
        for (int i = 0; i < formulainicial.length; i++) {
            // Procura por nutrientes que contem o mesmo nome e subistitue por valor do nutriente.,
            for (Nutriente n : nuts) {
                if (formulainicial[i].equalsIgnoreCase(n.getNome())) {
                    tempA[i] = String.valueOf(n.getQuantidade());
                }
            }

            if ("MO".equalsIgnoreCase(formulainicial[i])) {
                //Subistitue o texto "MO" pelo valor correspondente.
                tempA[i] = String.valueOf(ingrediente.getQuantidadedeMO())+"";
            }

            if ("total".equalsIgnoreCase(formulainicial[i])) {
                tempA[i] = String.valueOf(totaldeMO);
            }
        }

        listaF.add(contaItem, tempA);
        clone.getF().setCalculo(tempA);
        novosItems.add(contaItem, clone);
        contaItem++;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Se isso está acontecendo podem ser duas coisas, ou você está passando referencia do mesmo objeto para o ArrayList ou você está passando objetos diferentes porem idênticos.  Eu acredito que seja a segunda opção e que o problema esteja nessa linha de código:

`clone.getF().setCalculo(tempA);`.

Agora fica complicado afirmar com certeza sem saber como os métodos `getF()` e `setCalculo()` foram implementados implementados. Você pode postar o código deles?

Outra dica que eu dou é tentar destrinchar esse seu algorítimo em métodos menores que retornem o valor que você quer, da forma que está fica muito confuso de entender oque está acontecendo e dificulta a manutenção e teste do seu código. Quanto mais isoladas os blocos lógicos, mais orientado a objeto será seu código

Por exemplo, substitua isso:

```
for (int i = 0; i < formulainicial.length; i++) {
        // Procura por nutrientes que contem o mesmo nome e subistitue por valor do nutriente.,
        for (Nutriente n : nuts) {
            if (formulainicial[i].equalsIgnoreCase(n.getNome())) {
                tempA[i] = String.valueOf(n.getQuantidade());
            }
        }

        if ("MO".equalsIgnoreCase(formulainicial[i])) {
            //Subistitue o texto "MO" pelo valor correspondente.
            tempA[i] = String.valueOf(ingrediente.getQuantidadedeMO())+"";
        }

        if ("total".equalsIgnoreCase(formulainicial[i])) {
            tempA[i] = String.valueOf(totaldeMO);
        }
    }
```

Por algo mais assim:

```
    // Procura por nutrientes que contem o mesmo nome e subistitue por valor do     nutriente.,
public String substituiNutrientes(String formula){
    for (Nutriente n : nuts) {
                if (formula.equalsIgnoreCase(n.getNome())) {
                    return String.valueOf(n.getQuantidade());
                }
            }
    if ("MO".equalsIgnoreCase(formula)) {
                //Subistitue o texto "MO" pelo valor correspondente.
                return  String.valueOf(ingrediente.getQuantidadedeMO())+"";
            }
    if ("total".equalsIgnoreCase(formula)) {
                return String.valueOf(totaldeMO);
            }    
    return null; 
}


for (int i = 0; i < formulainicial.length; i++) {

    String formulaSubstituida = substituiNutrientes(formula)

    if(formulaSubstituida != null)tempA[i]  = formulaSubstituida;         

}
```